# Remove comma From the last value in a While loop

Tags: php

My main motive is to remove the comma ',' from the last value of the array.

```
$Followingcount = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from followers where follower_id = '$idnow'");
     if (mysqli_num_rows($Followingcount) > 0) {
    while ($ids = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Followingcount)) {
     $followedids = $ids['acc_id'].',';
     $array = array($followedids);
     $arraystr = implode("','",$array);
}}
```

If I `echo $followerdids` the result comes like this with commas like:

> 5, 7, 8,

To remove the comma at the last value I tried to place the values inside an array and then I imploded it.
When I `echo $arraystr` it still contains the comma at the last value.

Comment: I don't see how said output is being generated. I'd say the answers bellow are answering the Y in the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)...

Comment: It took me a while too, but in the end, he is adding a comma to the $followerids by himself ^^

Comment: Explanation on my previous comment: The op is not keeping the variable content with `,`, so, it should be overridding `$arraystr`, which would mean that basically the variable `$ids['acc_id']` already brings the values separated by `,` and the OP is adding the problem when they use `$ids['acc_id'].',';`. Edit: see [what I mean](https://eval.in/945006).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is:

```
$followedIds = [];

$followingCount = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from followers where follower_id = '$idnow'");
while ($ids = mysqli_fetch_assoc($followingCount )) {
     $followedIds[] = $ids['acc_id'];
}

echo implode(',', $followedIds);
```

...and take care of SQL Injection

Comment: I like this answer over the others, while the others are great and achieve the result, they appear more of a bandaid where as this is the fix

Comment: @Dale yeah, this is probably the only answer that considers the same as I mentioned in comments of question..

Comment: This [ ] means what?

Comment: It means, add a new element to the $followedIds array

Comment: `$followedIds = [];` is the same thing as `$followedIds = array()` but it was introduced since [PHP 5.4.0](http://php.net/manual/ro/migration54.new-features.php)

Answer (score 2):

You can use rtrim to remove the last comma after the while loop.

```
$followedids = rtrim($followedids, ',');
```

Comment: Always nice to see multiple possiblities for the same question! :)

Comment: Thanks I got the Answer! But the variable you used is not correct. It must be `$arraystr = rtrim($arraystr,',');`

Comment: Not really, the two lines exploding and imploding the array are not needed, so the variable is correct and should be done after the while loop. You only need to trim the string value right (rtrim).

Answer (score 2):

The solution to your problem is quite simple. There is a function called [rtrim](http://php.net/rtrim)(), which removes all characters on the right side.

```
$followedids = rtrim($followedids, ',');
```

There is also a [trim](http://php.net/trim)() function, which does the same on both sides, and [ltrim](http://php.net/ltrim)() which does it for the left side.

Comment: Thanks I got the Answer! But the variable you used is not correct. It must be `$arraystr = rtrim($arraystr,',');`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `substr`-function (more information [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php))

The last parameter is the length of the substring you want, but you can also use negative values, which means "remove this many characters", in your case: 1.

In your case:

```
$followedids = substr($followedids, 0,-1);
```